# UITableView Background Image for Static Section/Cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I know we can add background images/colors to section headers in dynamic table view/cells but can anyone help me do the same in a table view using Static Cells ?
What I want to do is use a background image for my 3rd section in a TableView which is using static cells (total of 4 sections it has)
I want to add a background image and change text color to say some RGB value for the 3rd section

[image: That Description section text color and BG is what I wanna change]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the delegate methods of UITableView to set the height and view for a section header. This should do what you want:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (section == 2)? 100:30;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    label.text = @"Description";
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [imageView addSubview:label];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"House.tiff"];
    return (section == 2)? imageView:nil;
}
```

Comment: I thought of this as using same way in dynamic table but can you tell me this, since my section is at 3rd position, you use "2" as its index number to check if its that section ? Also, is returning safe ? Do returning nil for section 0 1 3 makes it use the Section how it s designed in storyboard (using IB)

Comment: @user2897064, yes the index of the third section is 2, so that's why I test it that way. Returning nil for the other sections did leave those section with the titles that were set in IB -- they were identical to what I got if I didn't implement viewForHeaderInSection at all.

Comment: Cheers, tested and worked. The end result wasnt exactly as what I had in mind for the UI so I had to instead ditch sections and increase rows in 1 section, adding UI labels with BG image to act as section. But yeah that answered my question and would help me in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewCells` have the `backgroundView` property which is a `UIView`. You can change that to be a `UIImageView`, for example, or build a more complex background for you table view cells. It shouldn't matter, whether the cell is static or dynamic.

The text color for the cell can then simply be changed by setting the `UITableViewCells` `cell.textLabel.textColor`.

Same applies for the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, which are (as the name says) used for the header and footer of your table view sections. In code, you can access the header for a section using

```
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section
```

This saves you from completely recreating the header from scratch, just to make small adjustments. Alternatively, override

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and build a custom `UIView` that will become your header.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a tag(say 15) to the static cell in

```
tableview:didSelectRowForIndexPath
```

and then

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(cell.tag==15)
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0  green:250/255.0 blue:243/255.0 alpha:1.0];

}
```

Comment: err... please re-read what I asked, its not a cell, its a section what I need to work on. Even included a image to explain it